# Contact without account does not show for lookup value in force.com sites

Tags: force.com, sites

I have created a lookup field on my custom object to contact and it is used on visual force page. Also I have used custom lookup page.

In salesforce org it works fine and display lookup value. But when i use this page in sites then lookup value does not show for those contact which have no account.

If contact have account then it shown. I have already give permission to site users.

Answer (score 0):

Contacts without accounts are Private Contacts, and can only be viewed by the record owner.

The solution is to create a special account record, I usually call it "Orphanage".  Then relate these orphan contacts to that account.